# NodeJS: How do I escape special characters in SQL query for PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, sql, escaping

I've found few similar questions here, but no one contains sufficient answer.
Webapp has bunch of input fields. I need to escape all the special characters when i'm attempting to `INSERT` input's values into PG 9.5 database.
This one looks good:
[Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)
But it doesn't escape quotes. Due to this, I suppose, it may not escape other special characters.
Some other suggestions modifies the original value. E.g. if i'm posting a comment, and this comment contain one single quote, then i want to see exactly one single quote, when this comment gets rendered from database.

Comment: If you use parameterized SQL with stored procedure special characters shouldn't be a problem.also, you shouldn't escape special characters from the user input, or else, the outlook maybe different. How you're inserting record to the database..?

Comment: I'm using node-postgres (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)  
Client side sends json object to the nodejs server. Server has custom function, which transform json object into `INSERT` query.

Comment: Which language are you using on the code behind..? PHP?ASP.NET?

Comment: i'm using javascript

Comment: In that case, is it possible to use the "replace" function in javascript? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp e.g.: var insertStatement = youInsertStatement.replace("'", "''")

Comment: of course. I get what you mean. I'm able to write replace function. What i need is the 'replace' function, which replaces all the dangerous characters. Or, at least, a list of all such characters. I believe this is very common issue, I've just didn't found this function or the list of characters, which everyone uses.

Comment: function replaceSpecialCharacters(yourString){return yourString.replace("'", "''");}